# How to create a friends relationship in Hasura

Tags: hasura

I have 2 tables: `users` and `friends`.

`friends` has a `user_id` foreign key which obviously maps to the `users` `id` key.
`friends` also has a `friend_id` key which maps to the `users` `id` key as well.

I am using JWT Auth. I have successfully set the permission on the `users` table so that when the user queries for users the user pulls only that specific user's column. I have also created an array relationship for friends on the `users` table so `user` rows can have `friends` via the relationship.

However, when querying something like:

```
{
  user {
    username
    friends {
      id
      username
    }
  }
}
```

This returns null for friends, because the user role does not have access to friends (due to the session variable `X-Hasura-User-Id` used to determine user by session. How do I reconcile having the session variable work but also be able to query other friends?

Answer (score 1):

Put this permission on `friends`, and then users can see all friend rows where the `friend_id` is their `user.id`:

```
{
  "friend_id" :{
    "_eq" : "X-Hasura-User-Id"
   }
}
```

Permissions for relationships are inherited from the relationship table. So you just need to ensure that the user can regularly access the related table rows by themselves, and if you can do that it will apply to the relationships as well.

---

Unrelated, it looks like these tables have the same columns. You might want to use a self-referential relationship from `users`->`users` as `friends` if they're identical. If not ignore this =)

---

Edit:

Try using an `_exists` permission:

(You can probably simplify this using the relationships direct access to `friends` and `user` but I don't know your exact table and relationship structure)

"If there exists in table friends, a row where the 'friend_id' is 'X-Hasura-User-Id' and the 'user_id' is equal to this row's user ID"

```
{
  "_or": [
    {
      "_exists": {
        "_table": { "schema": "public", "name": "friends" },
        "_where": {
          "_and": [
            { "friend_id": { "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id" } },
            { "user_id": { "_ceq": "user_id" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    { "id": { "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id" } }
  ]
}
```

Comment: HI Gavin, thank you for answering. When I tried this, I still have the same issue. I have still restricted the users table select to just the user in the session. And when I try a query that joins to the user table, it returns null because of no permissions. I hope this makes sense.  can give full permission with no check on my friends table and it still does not work.

Comment: Ah. You should try adding a second "exists" permissions on "users" as well.

"If there exists in table `friends`, a row where the 'friend_id' is 'X-Hasura-User-Id' and the 'user_id' is equal to this row's user ID"

{
  "_or": [
    {
      "_exists": {
        "_table": { "schema": "public", "name": "friends" },
        "_where": {
          "_and": [
            { "friend_id": { "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id" } },
            { "user_id": { "_ceq": "user_id" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    { "id": { "_eq": "X-Hasura-User-Id" } }
  ]
}

Comment: If I do that then I will lose the session feature where when I query users, it only returns data for that one user right?

Comment: Oh do people usually just decode the JWT on the front end and query with the id as a param to get the user info.

Comment: Hasura decodes the JWT for you. So that permission will insert the current user's ID automatically from the JWT.

So each user will be able to see both themselves, or any user they are friends with, based on the ID of the current user.

Comment: This sis not work either because it allows the user to access all users if the relationship exists.